# TestNG dependsOnMethods from different class

Tags: java, testing, junit, automated-tests, testng

The `dependsOnMethods` attribute of the `@Test` annotation works fine when the test to be depended upon is in the same class as that of the test that has this annotation. But it does not work if the to-be-tested method and depended-upon method are in different classes. Example is as follows:

```
class c1 {
  @Test
  public void verifyConfig() {
    //verify some test config parameters
  }
}

class c2 {
  @Test(dependsOnMethods={"c1.verifyConfig"})
  public void dotest() {
    //Actual test
  }
}
```

Is there any way to get around this limitation? One easy way out is to create a test in `class c2` that calls `c1.verifyConfig()`. But this would be too much repetition.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Put the method in a `group` and use `dependsOnGroups`.

```
class c1 {
  @Test(groups={"c1.verifyConfig"})
  public void verifyConfig() {
    //verify some test config parameters
  }
}

class c2 {
  @Test(dependsOnGroups={"c1.verifyConfig"})
  public void dotest() {
    //Actual test
  }
}
```

It is recommended to verify configuration in a `@Before`* and throw if something goes wrong there so the tests won't run.  This way the tests can focus on just testing.

```
class c2 {
  @BeforeClass
  public static void verifyConfig() {
    //verify some test config parameters
    //Usually just throw exceptions
    //Assert statements will work
  }

  @Test
  public void dotest() {
    //Actual test
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working fine when running the the class file individual while running it through testing.xml file getting error  DependencyMap::Method "LoanApprovalTest.testLoanApprova(java.util.Hashtable)[pri:0, instance:com.zions.release1.Sanity.LoanTestCases.LoanApprovalTest@3884b2]" depends on nonexistent group "CreateLoanAccountTest.testCreateLoanAccount"

Comment: @ArpanSaini Both classes need to be under the same test.

Comment: Is writing the class name in the group name (c1) necessary? What if I want to club test methods from different classes in one group?

Answer (score 4):

## DependsOnMethods  cannot be used from different class ,To resolve this we can use dependsOnGroups;

## Do code change in;

## 1. dependsOnGroups class;

@Test(groups={"prerequisites" })

```
public void M1()
{

}
```

## 2. class which calls dependsOnGroups;

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups={"prerequisites"})
public void M2()

{

}
```

## 3. xml

```
<groups>
    <run>
        <include name ="prerequisites"/>
    </run>
</groups>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `groups` and `dependsOnGroups` in the TestNG `@Test` annotation, as described in earlier answers.

However, both classes need to be under the same `<test>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Test" >
    <classes>
       <class name="c1" />
       <class name="c2" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

The following will result in an exception when running the test suite.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Test1" >
    <classes>
       <class name="c1" />
    </classes>
  </test>

  <test name="Test2">
    <classes>
      <class name="c2" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions:
1. Using dependsOnGroups and inheritance

```
    import static org.testng.Assert.fail;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class PTest1 {
        @Test(groups = "A")
        public void test11() {
            System.out.println("test11");
            fail();
        }
    }


    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    public class PTest2 extends PTest1 {

        @Test(groups = "B", dependsOnGroups = "A")
        public void test21() {
            System.out.println("test21");
        }
    }


    <suite name="priority" verbose="1">
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name ="B"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <test name="pri2">
            <classes>            
                <class name="priority.PTest2"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
        <test name="pri1">
            <classes>            
                <class name="priority.PTest1"/>
            </classes>
        </test>    
    </suite>
```

2. Use programming：

   ```
   import static org.testng.Assert.fail;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;
   public class PTest3 {

       @Test
       public void test31() {
           System.out.println("test31");
           fail();
       }
   }

   import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
   import org.testng.ITestContext;
   import org.testng.SkipException;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class PTest4 {

       @Test
       public void test41(ITestContext context) {
           for (IInvokedMethod iInvokedMethod : context.getSuite().getAllInvokedMethods()) {
               if (iInvokedMethod.getTestMethod().getMethodName().equals("test31")
                       && !iInvokedMethod.getTestResult().isSuccess()) {
                   throw new SkipException("test31 is not sucessful!");
               }
           }
           System.out.println("test41");
       }
   }

   <suite name="priority" verbose="1">
       <test name="pri3">
           <classes>            
               <class name="priority.PTest3"/>
           </classes>
       </test>
       <test name="pri4">
           <classes>            
               <class name="priority.PTest4"/>
           </classes>
       </test>    
   </suite>
   ```